# Isolation of Google apps from Google search engine

Tags: forms, search, google-sheets, google-docs, google-contacts-api

I am a teacher. During this Covid-19 Pandemic, I am teaching online in Google Classroom. I use Google apps such as Docs, Sheets, Forms, Slides, Meet, Calendar, Gmail, etc. I find it impossible to stop students from visiting forbidden sites though we use NetRef to control their online surfing. Since Google Classroom uses Google apps, we cannot block google.com, and a result, it opens up infinite ways to surf the Internet.

Is it possible to separate **Google Classroom** and **Apps** from **Google Search Engine**? If so, it would be the only way to solve the problem that millions of teachers around the globe are facing.